# pfsense NAT DNS to different LAN IPs

Tags: firewall, pfsense

I have a pfsense firewall, and I need to NAT connection on WAN port 80 to LAN servers.

Ex:

server1.mydomain.com to 192.168.100.200

server2.mydomain.com to 192.168.100.201

I have no idea how to do that.

I have created the Host overrides like this example:

[image]

Then I have created a NAT rule with source any, destination wan interface and port 80, Redirect LAN address port 80 like this example:

[image]

But this is not fine.

The same rule with single host is working but obviously not differentiate hosts.

Comment: You have one external IP and want port 80 from there go to 2 different internal IPs?

Comment: Yes, i have only one external ip

Comment: You can not use NAT to have one destination port go to multiple internal machines. If you want this to be done on hostname, what you want is probably a reverse proxy doing the routing.